# Stored Procedures Overwhelming Oracle.EXE On Oracle 11g On Windows

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, cpu, cpu-usage

Until very recently we ran a 3rd party HR database on an Oracle Unix environment.  I have additionally set up various web services that hit stored procedures to carry out a few bespoke processes for our users, and all ran well for years.
However, now that we have moved to Oracle on a Windows environment there is suddenly a big problem.
The best example I have is a VB.Net solution that reads in a 2000 row CSV of employees into a datatable, runs a couple of stored procedures to bring back Post Id etc, populates a database table with the results, then feeds it all back out into a new CSV.  This process used to take 1-2 minutes to complete on Unix.  It now takes well over 2 hours and kills the server!
The problem manifests by overwhelming the CPU on the database server.  Any stored procedure call sends Oracle.EXE into overdrive, completely max-ing out the CPU core that it's using such that no other stored procedures can be run and everything grinds to a halt.
We have run Oracle Enterprise Manager, which suggested the creation of some indexes etc, but nothing will improve the issue.  Like I say, the SQL ran fine and swiftly for years, and it hasn't changed at all.

Does anybody know what could be causing this?  I am completely at a loss.

The way I see it, it must either be:
1. A CPU/hardware issue (but we have investigated, added extra cores etc to no avail)
2. An Oracle configuration issue?; or
3. An issue with the 3rd party database (which is supposedly identical to what it was on Unix).

Thanks to anyone who read this far.

P.S. I've had a Stack Overflow user account for years but can't get logged into it any more.  Back to noobie status for me!

Comment: You should at least mention Oracle version. But I doubt anybody will help you anyway. Your problem description is too generic. It's hard to help without seeing at least AWR report, memory sizing, HW configuration, ...

Comment: I mentioned it in the title - 11g.

Comment: I know, you're right.  I'm desperate enough to try anyway in case it rings a bell with someone.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: What is the HW setup on the server running Oracle?

Comment: VMware slice.  Two x64 CPU cores (Xeon X5650 2666Mhz), one socket.  8GB RAM.  Windows 2008 R2.

Comment: It's a dedicated server slice for the Oracle database.  The HR application runs on another server.  typically the CPU sits there doing very very little, then BOOM, I run a stored procedure and ORACLE.EXE goes wild and chokes up the CPU until it's finished.

Comment: Without seeing an AWR or explain plan on what the proc actually does my vote is open an Oracle SR assuming everything is supported.

Comment: The first step is to run the [profiler](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_profil.htm#ARPLS039) against the slow PL/SQL code and find the longest-running lines.  Some tools, like PL/SQL Developer, have a nice point-and-click GUI that allows you to run it, see the results, and sort the lines by time.  Chances are the longest running parts will be queries.  If you don't want to mess with PL/SQL, find the slowest SQL queries.  One simple method is: `select * from gv$sql order by elapsed_time desc;`.

Comment: Thanks to all who responded.

Comment: I have moved forward with this in a slightly unsatisfactory way.  I have ordered consultancy from the database provider to assist me in discovering the root of the problem, but in the meantime I have started making tables containing the entire contents of the output of the huge slow SQL queries that have been causing my issues.  This means that I am interrogating data that is no longer "live" but that was updated by a scheduled job that morning.  Now when I run a stored procedure to hit these new static tables, it returns instantly, rather than looping very slowly through live lengthy queries.